# Creating temporary tables perl cgi dbi

Tags: sql, perl, cgi, temp-tables, dbi

I have sql containing 8 table joins which takes time to fetch the data considering the amount of joins in the sql. I could create a temp table and simply the sql which might help speed up the data retrieval process.

i am trying to fetch the data using this sql in perl cgi dbi. Does it makes sense to create a temp table on a web application?

Comment: CGI is mostly presentation or view. DBI is mostly model. Although it makes sense to develop tools that bridge between them in common ways, developing an SQL for CGI, doesn't sound like the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have certainly used temp tables in SQL for a web application before.  The web application part really doesn't have anything to do with it.  Would a temp table make your SQL more efficient?  You'd have to be a lot more specific with your question for us to tell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i was just wondering if creating temp table would makes sense on  a web application when 100s of users will be creating temp table at a same time if they are accessing the same page.

Comment: Is the data fetched for the page the same for all concurrent users?  If so, you want/need some strong caching of the data.  Or is the data unique to each user, and reused by each user often as they visit?  If so, you want a per-user cache, maybe in a temporary table.  Or maybe the data is only used once, per-user per-page.  If so, temporary tables will win you little, but organizing your schema might.  Maybe a bit of de-normalizing is in order.

Comment: The case where temporary tables have been a clear win for me involved doing a few queries grouping and summing records in a table where some columns needed to be adjusted by a ratio determined by summing of records with the same grouping but a different where condition (if that makes sense).